# Removing tuples that have the same pair of values from a list

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, tuples

I want to remove all the tuples that have the same pair of values, e.g. `[(1,1), (2,3), (2,2), (3,4)]` I want `[(2, 3), (3, 4)]`. I am working in Haskell. This is what I tried:

```
unique [] = []
unique (x:xs) = if (fst x) == (snd x) then unique (xs) else x:[]
```

And the output was:

```
[(2,3)]
```

I am confused on why `(3, 4)` did not appear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because your `else` case says:

```
unique [] = []
unique (x:xs) = if (fst x) == (snd x) then unique (xs) else x:[]
```

It thus says if `fst x` is *not* equal to `snd x`, then we return `x : []` (or shorter `[x]`), and we are done. So it does *not* perform recursion on the rest of the list.

We can solve this by adding recursion on the rest of the list, like:

```
unique [] = []
unique (x:xs) = if fst x == snd x then unique xs else x : unique xs
```

That being said, we can use a filter here, like:

```
unique :: Eq a => [(a, a)] -> [(a, a)]
unique = filter (\(x, y) -> x /= y)
```

or even shorter:

```
unique :: Eq a => [(a, a)] -> [(a, a)]
unique = filter (uncurry (/=))
```

We thus retain all elements for which the first element `x` is *not* equal to the second element `y`.

Comment: Not sure how to use the last one (the parameter it needs and where to use it), however  I used the first option you said and It works and makes sense. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Hammad: due to *eta-reductions*, you don't need to mention that parameter. If you define `f y = g x y`, then that is equivalent to `f = g x`, so you simply define it as `unique = filter (uncurry (/=))`, and than that function has type `Eq a => [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]`, so you can use it exactly the same way (like `unique [(1,2), (2,2), (3,4), (4,3), (4,4)]`.